# In Eclipse my src folder is missing

Tags: java, eclipse

I am a beginner coder, and this is my first time using Eclipse. I have started my new (Java) project and everything is going well until I look at the file explorer. In my project folder I have a JRE system library, but no src folder. Is there a way to start a new src folder?

Picture of the file explorer

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Tipically a Java Project contains by default a src folder, I don't know the reason your project don't have this folder, but you can create source folders.

In Eclipse, right click on the project and select New > Other. Then type source and create a new one with the name src.

[new source folder wizard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8aTm.png)

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse, right click on the project and select New > Other. Then type source and create a new one with the name src.

Or

Please select following menu

File>menu>new java project

select From Projecy layout tab : create seperate folders for sources and class files